# SQL - Cannot bulk load

Tags: sql, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to perform a bulk upload of multiple CSV files to SSMS.
I have the table created with the appropriate column names but when I execute my code the access to the folder containing the CSV files is denied.

I have read online that you need to store the files in the same location that the server is on but this is not an option for me.

I have also tried to edit the permissions of the folder that the CSV files are in but the access is still denied.

Does anyone have a solution to this, I've spent hours trying to find one.

**My Code**

**1. Create a table to store CSV info.**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_cube](
    [Name] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Country][nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Occupation][nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Hobby][nvarchar](1000) NULL
) on [Primary]
```

**2. Create table to store information on the imported files**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[files_logtable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [filename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [date_created] [datetime] DEFAULT GETDATE()
)ON [Primary]
```

**3. Create a stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE import_files @filepath varchar(500), @pattern varchar(100), @tablename varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @query varchar(1000), @moveProcessed varchar(1000)

CREATE TABLE #x(name varchar(200))

set @query = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir '+@filepath+@pattern+' /b"'

insert #x exec (@query)

delete from #x where name IS NULL

select identity(int,1,1) as ID,name into #y from #x

drop table #x

Declare @max1 int, @count1 int, @filename varchar(200)

set @max1 = (select max(ID) from #y)

set @count1 = 0

while @count1 < @max1
BEGIN
SET @count1 = @count1+1

SET @filename = (select name from #y where [id]=@count1)

set @query = 'BULK INSERT '+@tablename+' FROM "'+@filepath+@filename+'" WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',FIRSTROW=1,ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'')'

EXEC (@query)

insert into file_logtable(filename) select @filename

set @moveProcessed = 'MOVE "'+@filepath+@filepath+'" C:\Users\cob2202\Desktop\Files\Data Cube\FlatFileDestination\"'+SUBSTRING(@filename,1, LEN(@filename) -4)+'_'+cast(FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyMMDDHHmmss') as varchar)+'.csv"'


EXEC master..XP_cmdshell @moveProcessed
END

END
```

**4. Read in files**

```
Exec import_files 'C:\Users\cob2202\Desktop\Files\Data Cube\FlatFileSource\', '*.csv', 'data_cube'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that sql server service has permission to access the folder?